# Simple database insert and delete via Ajax in Django application

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a Django application that involves various people, companies, and products. I'd like to include the ability for logged in users to "favorite" any number of those people, companies, and products. I'm a pretty new Django developer and my knowledge of Javascript is scant, so I'm struggling to apply the existing Django/Ajax tutorials to my situation. Here's what I have so far. I'm going to include just the bits about favoriting a person since I presume that solution for favoriting companies and products will be virtually identical.

```
# models.py (relevant tables only)
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # many other irrelevant fields omitted


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    fav_people = models.ManyToManyField(Person,
                                        through='FavoritePerson',
                                        through_fields=('user', 'person'),
                                        related_name='users',
                                        )
    fav_companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company,
                                           through='FavoriteCompany',
                                           through_fields=('user', 'company'),
                                           related_name='users',
                                           )
    fav_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,
                                          through='FavoriteProduct',
                                          through_fields=('user', 'product'),
                                          related_name='users',
                                          )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Custom Users'

    def __str__(self):
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
        else:
            return f"{self.username}"


class FavoritePerson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='favorite_people'
                             )
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               related_name='favorite_people', )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Favorited People'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} - {self.person}"
```

Here's the relevant portion of my template where it displays a star outline if the person isn't a favorite and a filled-in star if the person is a favorite of the logged-in user. I'm using the [django-fontawesome-5](https://pypi.org/project/django-fontawesome-5/) package for the icons.

```
<!-- person_detail.html -->
<section id="entity-details">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="entity-bio-col">
      {% if person in user.fav_people.all %}
        {% fa5_icon 'star' 'fas' color='white' size='fa-xs' title='One of your favorite pros' %}
      {% else %}
        {% fa5_icon 'star' 'far' color='white' size='fa-xs' title='Favorite this pro' %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

All I need to do is to insert a row in the FavoritePerson table when I click the star outline and delete that row in the table when I click on a filled-in star. I'd like this to work without a page refresh, hence the Ajax approach.

Would someone be willing to provide a solution? I can take it and run from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to make this work.

```
// Delete record from CustomUser.FavoritePerson table
function deletePersonFavorite(id) {
  var action = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this favorite?");
  if (action !== false) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "person_favorite_ajax_delete" %}',
        data: {
            'person': '{{ person.id }}',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.deleted) {
              $("#star #fave-button").remove();
              $("#star").append('<a role="button" id="unfave-button" class="btn" size="fa-lg" style="border: 0;" onClick="createPersonFavorite()"><i class="far fa-star fa-lg" style="color:white;" title="Favorite this pro"></i></a>');
            }
        }
    });
  }
}

// Add a record to the CustomUser.FavoritePerson table
function createPersonFavorite() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "person_favorite_ajax_create" %}',
        data: {
            'person': '{{ person.id }}',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.favorite_person_record) {
                $("#star #unfave-button").remove();
                $("#star").append('<a role="button" id="fave-button" class="btn" size="fa-lg" style="border: 0;" onClick="deletePersonFavorite()"><i class="fas fa-star fa-lg" style="color:white;" title="Unfavorite this pro"></i></a>');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here are the views.

```
# views.py
class CreatePersonFavorite(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        custom_user = request.user
        favorite_person = Person.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('person', None))

        obj = FavoritePerson.objects.create(
            person = favorite_person,
            user = custom_user,
        )

        favorite_person_record = {'id':obj.id, 'user':obj.user.id, 'person':obj.person.id}

        data = {
            'favorite_person_record': favorite_person_record
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)


class DeletePersonFavorite(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        custom_user = request.user
        favorite_person = Person.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('person', None))

        FavoritePerson.objects.filter(
            person = favorite_person,
            user = custom_user
        ).delete()
        data = {
            'deleted': True
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

And finally.

```
# urls.py
    path('ajax/personfavorite/create/', CreatePersonFavorite.as_view(), name='person_favorite_ajax_create'),
    path('ajax/personfavorite/delete/', DeletePersonFavorite.as_view(), name='person_favorite_ajax_delete'),
```

It's all working perfectly. I hope someone can benefit from this.